# Good way to serialize a list? - Javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, serialization

just felt like asking this as there are always jewels popping up on stackoverflow :)

What I have is the following list:

```
list1 = [['command','arg1','arg2'], ['command2','arg1'], ... ]
```

**How would you recommend to transform it into a string in order to be passed as ONE GET argument?**

e.g.

```
http://webgame_site.com/command_list/?data=...
```

---

What I am currently doing is separating lists using commas `,` `;` , but I don't like this idea as the method would break if I decide to introduce these within strings.

I'm trying to be as compact as possible.

---

**One idea I've had is to encode the list into base64:**

```
[['command','arg1','arg2'], ['command2','arg1']]
=> "W1snY29tbWFuZCcsJ2FyZzEnLCdhcmcyJ10sWydjb21tYW5kMicsJ2FyZzEnXV0="
```

which is shorter than URIencode

---

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert it to json then encode the characters using encodeURI.

```
var list1 = [['command','arg1','arg2'], ['command2','arg1']];
var encoded = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(list1));

alert(encoded);
```

Edit for base64:

```
var list1 = [['command','arg1','arg2'], ['command2','arg1']];
var encoded = btoa(JSON.stringify(list1));

alert(encoded);
alert(atob(encoded));
```

Comment: @david: thanks for this! Any ideas on how I could reduce the length of the string?

Comment: not really, you could try base64 encoding (I'll add it to the answer) but if you're passing truly huge lists you should probably be using a post.

Comment: Oh, ahaha you had the same idea ><

Comment: @david: haha we posted at the same time! :) btw post would be good if I could get cross-domain POSTing working. One of the panes is that IE limits the length of URLs.

Comment: The people here did some crazy stuff with iframes to get cross domain posts working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Comment: @david This is the solution that I thought of.  Also, POST is better for large strings.

Comment: @david: found out that URLs max_length in real world is 2000 characters... I guess this is duable.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)  sounds good.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply! :) Unfortunately the method vastly inflates data, I'm trying to be as compact as possible.